# How to use Two Factor with Github Organization plugin

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

We are enforcing Two Factor Authentication on all users in our GitHub Organization.

When we enabled it, all of our Jenkins jobs were fine EXCEPT for our "Github Organization" jobs.

It seems this plugin only support username/password creds, not id_rsa or access_tokens, which work fine with Two Factor Authentication.

If you use username/access_token credentials, you get access denied:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: 
[https://api.github.com/]
    at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:243)
    at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.huc.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.getInputStream(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:210)
    at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:25)
    at org.kohsuke.github.Requester.parse(Requester.java:612)
    at org.kohsuke.github.Requester.parse(Requester.java:594)
    at org.kohsuke.github.Requester._to(Requester.java:272)
Caused: org.kohsuke.github.GHFileNotFoundException: \{"message":"Must specify two-factor authentication OTP code.","documentation_url":"
[https://developer.github.com/v3/auth#working-with-two-factor-authentication]
"}
    at org.kohsuke.github.Requester.handleApiError(Requester.java:686)
    at org.kohsuke.github.Requester._to(Requester.java:293)
    at org.kohsuke.github.Requester.to(Requester.java:234)
    at org.kohsuke.github.GitHub.checkApiUrlValidity(GitHub.java:703)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.github_branch_source.GitHubSCMSource.checkApiUrlValidity(GitHubSCMSource.java:1348)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.github_branch_source.GitHubSCMSource.retrieve(GitHubSCMSource.java:1401)
    at jenkins.scm.api.SCMSource.fetch(SCMSource.java:564)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.multibranch.SCMBinder.create(SCMBinder.java:95)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowRun.run(WorkflowRun.java:295)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:429)
Finished: FAILURE
```

I entered a ticket here (I'm not sure if this is a bug or if there is a workaround, hence I'm cross-posting here)
https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-51092

Even the help text says it only supports username/password combos (image attached).

The top of my config.xml file for this project is this:

It looks like this has been fixed in other places, but not this plugin:
https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-39477